# How to write expression to convert yyyymm to mm-yyyy in ssrs?

Tags: date, reporting-services, format

1. I have a table with a YearMonth column (201302) in it.
2. I created YearMonth a parameter.

Now I would like to write an expression in SSRS so that every time the report runs the date and month would look like this **Feb-2013**.

Could you please suggest me why following expression did not work.

Thanks

```
=CStr(Right(MonthName(Month(Parameters!NLR_YearMonth.Value)),3))
 + "-" + 
 Left(Year(Parameters!NLR_YearMonth.Value),4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
=Format(DateValue(MonthName(Right(Parameters!NLR_YearMonth.Value, 2))
 + "," + 
 Left(Parameters!NLR_YearMonth.Value,4)), "Y")
```

The expression goes as follows:

1. Cutting the string to get the month.
2. Converting the mount to `MountName`
3. Creating a comma seperator between the month and the year
4. Cutting the string to get the year
5. Converting the returns string to `Date` object using the `DateValue` function
6. Formatting the Date to fits your needs

The results should be:
February, 2013